# Second $.ajax call stuck the code

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have an ajax+jquery navigation system with $.ajax, and I`m trying to do a second call to $.ajax to send a contact form infos, but, when I add the second $.ajax all just stop working.

First Call -

```
function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#!','');

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "loader.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#conteudo').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Second Call

```
$("#enviar").click(function() {  

    var str = $("form").serializeArray();

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "update.php",  
        data: str, 
        success: function(mn) { 

            if(parseInt(mn)!=0)
            {

            $("#conteudo").html(mn);
            $("#enviado").css('visibility','visible');

            }

    }

    return false;

});
```

@EDIT

Very good! The first ajax is not stucking anymore, but this second is not working as expected.

This is intended to parse $_POST values to a php script and if ok just turn div visible..

How I`m doing that -

```
<form name="formcontato" id="form">
  <fieldset>
    <label>Seu nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" class="input-block-level">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="seu@email.com" class="input-block-level">

    <div class="form-actions">
    <input type="button" name="enviar" value="Enviar" id="enviar" class="btn btn-baixar" />  
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the form.

```
$("#enviar").click(function () {

    var str = $("#form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: str,
        success: function (mn) {

            alert("Ok!");

            if (parseInt(mn) != 0) {

                $("#conteudo").html(mn);
                $("#enviado").css('visibility', 'visible');

            }

        }

    });

    return false;

});
```

This is the js

```
if($_POST) {

$nome = trim($_POST['nome']);
echo $nome;

}
```

This is the update.php

Answer (score 1):

In what you posted, the second function does not properly close the `$.ajax()` function with a `});` so it would generate a parse error and none of the code in this block would be available.

Try this where the `$.ajax()` call is succesfully closed.

```
$("#enviar").click(function () {

    var str = $("form").serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: str,
        success: function (mn) {

            if (parseInt(mn) != 0) {

                $("#conteudo").html(mn);
                $("#enviado").css('visibility', 'visible');

            }

        }

    });

    return false;

});
```

FYI, proper and consistent indentation is essential to spotting these issues.

Comment: @JordanMiguel - Sorry, but I don't know PHP.  StackOverflow is meant for you to continue editing your question to add more and more problems.  It's meant to be you ask a question, we provide an answer, you accept the best answer that solve that question.  If you have more questions after that, you ask a new question.

Comment: @JordanMiguel - I'd suggest you put a breakpoint or `console.log()` in the success handler for the second ajax function and see what `mn` is.

Comment: I'm sorry for that! I put a console.log(mn); into function but when I click this doesn't shows anything..

Comment: @JordanMiguel - then you need to look in the error console to see if any script errors are happening which is stopping execution or you need to install an error handler function (just like your `success:` function and see what error is happening with a `console.log()` in the error function.  This is basic javascript debugging.  You need to learn how to use the tools to see when you have errors and where the errors are.  Since we can't run your code to see that info, we can't do more than advise you to use the tools yourself to get more info.

Comment: I used firebug to check if my code had errors, and this doesn't return any errors. :/

Comment: @JordanMiguel - then the next step is to determine if the ajax call is getting to your server by examining something on the server.  If it is, then you need an error handler on the ajax call to look for an error return.  See the `error` option for `jQuery.ajax()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).